# org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: no sigar-amd64-winnt.dll in java.library.path

Tags: java, windows

dependency for my test program is org.fusesource.sigar and I have also added sigar-1.6.4.jar in my classpath.  I understand that adding sigar-amd64-winnt.dll to my classpath might help, the question is where do I find this file?  I have searched and even tried to download it without any success.

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated in this regard

```
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: no sigar-amd64-winnt.dll in java.library.path
        at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.loadLibrary(Sigar.java:172)
        at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.<clinit>(Sigar.java:100)
        at org.hyperic.sigar.win32.Win32.<clinit>(Win32.java:29)
        at com.mycompany.testadobeinstalled.TestAdobe.main(TestAdobe.java:28)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.hyperic.sigar.win32.RegistryKey.RegOpenKey(JLjava/lang/String;)J
        at org.hyperic.sigar.win32.RegistryKey.RegOpenKey(Native Method)
        at org.hyperic.sigar.win32.RegistryKey.openSubKey(RegistryKey.java:221)
        at com.mycompany.testadobeinstalled.TestAdobe.main(TestAdobe.java:28)
```

Answer (score 8):

Download the sigar package [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sigar/files/sigar/1.6/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip/download).

Unzip the file and browser to sigar-bin/lib. In this folder are all DLL's.

Comment: Where to put the dll file? A folder exactly named java.library.path in the same directory?

Comment: java.library.path is a property, for know the value uses System.getProperty("java.library.path"). So you will know which folders you can put the dll file.

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the folder, there you can find the `sigar-amd64-winnt.dll` in bin. Place that file in `c:/programfile/jdk/bin`